# Does a subclass go in a separate file?

Tags: objective-c, class, oop

I know that this may be personal preference but generally there are normal programming practices. So I am wondering if I created a class and a subclass would they go in separate files or the same one? I am talking in relation to objective-c but also in general.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't HAVE to, but generally speaking, yes.  Keeping a subclass in the same file would be the exception to the rule.

First of all, you shouldn't just pile tons of code into a single file.  Keep things simple so they're easier to understand when you look back at them later or when someone else has to look through your code to maintain it.

But if the two classes are so simple that you think you can fit all the code into one file and it still be simple enough to understand, then are you sure you need to subclass the original class?  Why are you subclassing instead of just expanding the original class?

Moreover, what if you decide later that you want to add more subclasses.  For example, a file with a `Vehicle` class may be extremely barebones.  Then you subclass that and create `Car` class and figure it's still pretty simple, so I'll just keep it in the same file.  But what happens when you decide to add more subclasses to `Vehicle`, like `Plane` and `Boat`.  A file with `Vehicle`, `Car`, `Plane`, and `Boat` is definitely not the right approach.  And a set up that has `Vehicle` and its subclass `Car` in the same file, but `Vehicle's` other subclasses, `Plane` and `Boat` are in their own files?  Now this is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason to have classes in separate files is to enforce separation of concerns. By making it impossible to accidentally use private implementation details, you make it much easier to make statements like "only this class knows about this code/data, therefore I can change it freely as long as I make sure the interface to this class still behaves the same way".

The boundaries of your files then match the boundaries of what you have to keep in your head at any given moment, and the #import'ed @interfaces form the connections between the isolated areas.